# Access VBA - Turn off aggregation when opening form/sub-form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

What I'm trying to do is, whenever a user opens a form (and the sub-form that opens by default), I want to search through all the columns (controls?) on the form, check to see if they are currently set to aggregate (sum, count etc.) with Access' built-in Totals row, and if so, set them to not aggregate.

The reason for this is there are several millions records that are stored, so when someone queries it down to 3-4 and turns on Sum, then closes it, when the next person opens it, it tries to sum millions of numbers and freezes up. The form displays the queried results from a table which is populated via SQL (I think, if that sentence makes sense). Here's what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
'this form_load is in the UserApxSub sub-form, for reference
Call De_Aggregate
End Sub

Private Sub De_Aggregate()
Dim frm As Form, con As Control

Set frm = Forms!UserAPX!UserApxSub.Form!

For Each con In frm.Controls
    If con.ControlType = acTextBox Then
        If con.Properties("AggregateType").Value <> -1 Then
            'crashes on following line
            con.Properties("AggregateType").Value = -1
        End If
    End If
Next con

End Sub
```

I have not so much experience in Access VBA (usually work in Excel VBA) so please forgive me if I'm entirely off the mark here. The command `con.Properties("AggregateType").Value = -1` doesn't throw an error, but Access just straight-up crashes when reaching that line specifically.

I've tried a number of variations in the syntax with no success, and I've also tried looping through other elements of the file (tabledefs, querydefs, recordsets, etc.) as well to see if I'm trying to change the wrong value, but the controls on this subform are the only things in the entire .mdb file that results when I search for elements with the AggregateType property.

I switched out the line that errors with `Debug.Print con.Name & " - " & con.Properties("AggregateType").Value` and I can check, have nothing return anything other than -1, turn on aggregation in some column manually, and have it return the correct result (0 for sum for example), so I think I'm looking in the right place, just missing some key factor.

I've been working on this for a couple weeks with no success. Any way to fix what I have or point me toward the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you don't want aggregates in your form, can't you just set the form's record source to something that doesn't contain aggregates?

Comment: If I'm understanding what you mean correctly, I can't turn off aggregation entirely, as users need to be able to use it. I essentially just can't have them leave it on when they close the form since it'll still be on when the next person opens it.

Comment: Not entirely. Aggregation is controlled by the text box's control source, and the form's record source. If users have to use it, you could just try If `con.Properties("AggregateType").Value <> -1 Then
            con.ControlSource = ""
        End If`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not seem to work (it cleared the column of all data entirely).

Answer (score 1):

> This is not necessarily the answer but I don't have enough reputation
>   to give a "comment"...

I tried your scenario and verified can change the property value as you are however I did not iterate through all controls and simply used an onDoubleClick event on a column to simulate.

I would suggest trying to fire your sub with Form_Open or Form_Current to see if the property is getting reset after your code has been called for some reason.

**UPDATE:**

You are referencing the "Subform" Object of your main Form:

```
Set frm = Forms!UserAPX!UserApxSub.Form!
```

Try referencing the actual `UserApxSub` FORM explicitly.

Something like `Set frm = Forms!UserApxSub!` (assuming UserApxSub is the name of the form)

then stick in the `Form_Open` of your main form:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
'// the following would set a single control only. You can add your loop through all controls
Me!{your control name}.Properties("AggregateType").Value = -1 '// set control in your main form
Form_UserApxSub!{your control name}.Properties("AggregateType").Value = -1 '// set control in your "sub" form
End Sub
```

Comment: I made some progress with this based on your advice. I didn't have any luck in calling the sub from Form_Open, Form_Current, Form_Load, etc., but I tried calling it from Form_**Un**load in the main Form (not the Subform) and it *kinda* works. The debug.prints I have set up show that it is correctly changing the AggregateType to -1, but it's not saving the change (as soon as I re-open the form, it's back to aggregating again). Tried a number of save methods (`DoCmd.Save acForm, "UserAPX"`, `DoCmd.Close acForm, "UserApxSub", acSaveYes`, etc.) with no success so I'm thinking I'm close. Any ideas?

Comment: See my UPDATE in above Answer.

Comment: `Set frm = Forms!UserApxSub!` threw an error, namely "[filename] cannot find the referenced form 'UserApxSub'". I tried putting `Form_UserApxSub!GROSSAMT.Properties("AggregateType") = -1` (as GROSSAMT is one of the controls that will need to be checked) into the `Form_Open` event for UserApx (the main form), and it froze again like before, but I was able to get a screenshot of the error while I was shutting it down this time, which said "Method 'Properties' of object '_Textbox' failed".

Comment: Hmm...  Something seems amiss...  I'd have to look at the accdb file to see whats going on.  Are you hard set on using the "datasheet view" of your form/subform?  if you used "form view", you give yourself much more power and freedom to customize your users' experience. (although this may not be possible depending on your project).

Comment: I'm afraid you've lost me with 'datasheet view': I don't think the .mdb is using that (guess I don't know for sure). I'd be happy to upload the whole thing but unfortunately it's proprietary (I'm just supposed to fix this one little part of it and not touch anything else). It's starting to sound like there's something going on in the background that's making this impossible for me to fix as it is right now, so I might just call it quits.